# Does $E=mc^2$ mean that an object with mass $m$ travels at the speed of light in empty space?

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light, mass-energy

I cannot wrap my head around this (Im new to physics), and this concept is troubling me. I think no, but im not sure why?

Comment: No, it means that if the object is annihilated by antimatter E will be the energy released

Comment: Not sure why you think that would be an interpretation. Maybe this comes out of confusion over [Mass in special relativity § The relativistic mass concept](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_in_special_relativity#The_relativistic_mass_concept).

Comment: It mostly means that you are taking one part of the complete relationship out of its context because you are taught by the media that somehow half of the truth is still the truth. In this case half a formula is simply a broken formula.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out what made you think this in the first place, and all I can imagine is that you interpreted $E$ as kinetic energy, and set $E=mv^2/2$.  But in that case, you should have concluded that an object of mass $m$ travels at $\sqrt{2}$ times the speed of light.

Answer (score 3):

No, it doesn't. It just means that particle of mass $m$ can be converted to $mc^2$ of energy. You can find a good popular article on that topic here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass%E2%80%93energy_equivalence

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xo232kyTsO0 "Mass $m$ can be converted to energy $mc^2$." is not a perfectly alright statement. Have a look at the video attached!

Answer (score 2):

No. It means that when one is accounting for the total energy of the system one must account for the energy contribution of the mass. It also means that the mass isn't necessarily conserved in a system, while energy and momentum will be.  In special cases, energy and/or momentum may even be constant in an defined subsystem.

The quantity $E^2- p^2c^2$ of a subsystem will remain constant, where $$E = \Sigma \left(m_jc^2+K_j\right)$$ with $m_j$ being the mass of particle $j$ and $K_j$ being the kinetic energy of particle $j$, and $$p^2=\vec{p}\cdot\vec{p}$$
where $\vec{p}=\Sigma \vec{p}_j$, the vector sum of the individual momenta. The total mass can change if the kinetic energy and individual momenta change.

Answer (score 2):

No. It means that the energy content of a particle at rest whose mass is $m$ is equal to $mc^2$. In general, $E=\dfrac{mc^2}{\sqrt{1-\dfrac{v^2}{c^2}}}$ represents the energy content of a particle of mass $m$ moving with a speed $v$. If it is at rest, i.e. $v=0$, then $E=mc^2$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, relative to a photon, all objects of mass $m$ are moving at the speed of light in empty space.

(Note however no observer can really travel at the speed of light, but as they approach the speed of light their observations approach what I've described)